# Graphics issue with steam game and ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, graphics, games, steam, intel

So I recently installed Ubuntu in one of my machines to play a game called Dota 2. Game used to run on this machine fine while on windows but since updating to Ubuntu 14 I get a issue of game not starting up.

I get a window called

"**Unable To Start Game"**

**Failed to create an OpenGL context.**

**Your graphics card must support at least OpenGL 3.1.**"

Am I missing some files or is Ubuntu Dota just no compatible with my machine. if that is is the case I would have to revert back into windows. Shame too as I am really enjoying the linux experience.

Hope someone can help me out here.

EDIT:
*-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:27 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4050(size=8)

name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-afff809 2015-10-16 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, 
    GL_ARB_clip_control, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, 
    GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 
    GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, 
    GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_INTEL_performance_query, 
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_MESA_pack_invert, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-afff809 2015-10-16 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, 
    GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_draw_buffers, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rg, GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, 
    GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, GL_INTEL_performance_query, 
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_NV_draw_buffers, 
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_read_buffer, GL_NV_read_depth, 
    GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_sync, 
    GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture, GL_OES_depth24, GL_OES_depth_texture, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
    GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer, GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil8, 
    GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot, 
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object

24 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x084 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x086 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x087 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x088 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x089 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x08b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x093 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x096 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x05e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

36 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x05f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x060  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x061  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x063 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x067 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x069 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06b  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x06d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x071  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x075 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x07f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x081 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
```

Comment: Have you got an Ubuntu compatible version or are you using the Windows version in something like Wine or PlayOnLinux?

Comment: If you have an Ubuntu compatible version running in Steam, then perhaps you should try and get the Windows version of Steam and Dota 2 running PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Start the terminal with ctrl + alt + t, and please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/686653/edit) your question with the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `glxinfo`

Comment: @Wildcard not sure I i edited it in correctly.

Comment: @Paranoid Panda It is the Ubuntu version of steam

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the latest update disaster but common over the years.  Apparently new lib* files are not compatible with OpenGl and steam.  Its an Ubuntu side, not steam side error. Basically the fix is not standardized but I would start with this..

15.0+ workaround

So enter this folders and do this (ignore the x86_64 if you only have a 32bit system):

```
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

14.02

```
 rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

Also try:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 \
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 \
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 \
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 \
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

14.04 files...

```
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

Next I would look for

```
 /SteamApps/common/[game name]/bin/ folder for libstdc++.so.6
```

and rm it.

Both /steamapps/ and /.steam/ contain these files and I would look in them folders for matching files.   The name of the lib* files keep updating, so its tough to find which one isincompatible.  A quick way to determine this is

Answer (score 0):

Seems your graphic card is incompatible with the game. The game requires OpenGL version 3.1 at least and your graphic card provides OpenGL version 2.1.

To be more precisely, your processor and on-board graphic card is from 5th generation (Ironlake) and Dota 2 requires a Intel HD Graphics 3000, present in 6th generation (Sandy Bridge) processors. So no game for you.Sorry.